# Hash join hint returns an error when using local variable

Tags: sql-server, execution-plan, sql-server-2019, parameter, hints

The query below is using the StackOverflow2010 sample database:

```
DECLARE @Id INT = 18471

SELECT c.UserId FROM dbo.Comments AS c
INNER HASH JOIN dbo.Users AS u
ON c.UserId = u.Id
AND c.UserId = @Id
```

With a hash join hint, it returns the following error:

> Query processor could not produce a query plan because of the hints
> defined in this query. Resubmit the query without specifying any hints
> and without using SET FORCEPLAN

It works when I add `OPTION(RECOMPILE)` or replace the variable with a string literal.

What could be causing this issue?

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying. The original query is using hash join hint to deal with a parameter sniffing issue. The query above is just a simple sample to replicate the issue found.

Comment: This is because of implied predicates. There is a Craig Freedman blog post explaining it that I have linked previously on this site

Comment: @MartinSmith That does seem plausible, but why would the error only occur when using local variables and not with literals and OPTION(RECOMPILE)?

Comment: Not sure at the moment. The blog post explaining why you get this some times is https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/craigfr/implied-predicates-and-query-hints

Comment: Is it a theoretical question, or do you think you really need a `HASH JOIN` for this query? With `Comments.UserId` fixed, `Users.Id` is fixed, too. Whereas there is only one user with any specified `Id`, the whole join operation is redundant. Futhermore, the `Users` table is not required at all: `SELECT UserId FROM Comments WHERE UserId = @Id`. Even futhermore, the query does not make any sense to me because it returns the given `Userid` in as many rows as there are comments by that user. What is the use of this redundant data?